# How can I handle keypresses before Visual Studio does?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, events, keyboard, vsx

In my VS add-in, I need to handle key presses (presumably via `PreTranslateAccelerator()`) before Visual Studio does. Unfortunately, after digging in `Shell.Interop`, I can't find the location where I would be able to handle them. Can anyone help?

Comment: And why would you need to do this?

Comment: I need to know what modifier key (Ctrl, Alt, etc.) the user is holding down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my project, I use IOleCommandTarget interface to intercept key press in visual studio. There is a method named "QueryStatus" after you implement the IOleCommandTarget. I think you can use this method to handle keypress before visual studio does. You can also decide whether  transfer msg chain to VS. I found this article that may help [you.http://www.ngedit.com/a_intercept_keys_visual_studio_text_editor.html](http://www.ngedit.com/a_intercept_keys_visual_studio_text_editor.html)